# How to create new vue-cli project inside existing vue-cli project?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

In angular, i can able to create new angular-cli application inside existing angular-cli application using below command

```js
npm run ng generate application window
```

**But in Vue-cli, i don't know how to do it. Is there anyway  to do this?**

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: https://github.com/BanupriyaSelvaraj/ej2-vue-samples ........ this is my application i want create individual bundle for all samples so that i need this kind of option. if i had this option i will create new cli and use gulp task to copy samples code and paste into ew cli application and take build for that sample

Comment: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/material/grid/over-view in her you can see button near `edit in stackblitz` button if you click that it will open same sample individually. i want to achieve this in vue